Is there a way to dynamically turn an input on and off during runtime?
I have a use case for Fluent Bit such that I'd like to enable/disable an input on the fly. The reasoning behind this is that I have some trace log files that I need to monitor with fairly high volume of writes. But there may be certain conditions where monitoring the trace logs is necessary.
If I can disable the trace log monitoring when it is not needed, then it would reduce Fluent Bit's resource usage to a minimum during times when the trace logs don't need to be monitored.
Is there currently a built-in way to do this in Fluent Bit without restarting it?

https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/development/library_api

This is possible using hot-reload in Fluent-bit and having a way to edit or write the configuration file dynamically then triggering the hot-reload of configuration. It is important to remember when using Tail to ensure you don't use a database file to track what you've not set read_from_head.
I'd recommend not taking this approach and using dynamic changing of the log level within your application if possible.
